# How to pass parameters / arguments using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chooseLocationType(location, title, demand){
        alert(demand);
        }
```

```
<body>
<input 
    name="tempstaff_location" 
    class="ques_radio" 
    id='tempstaff_location'
    value='location_' 
    type="radio" onclick="chooseLocationType('a','b','c')" />
</body>
```

I have the folowing code, on click of the radio box ,
There is one conditional code based on this to show hide some dive.

And there is one more jQuery script which run on Click and used function.

jQuery(this)

```
input[name=tempstaff_location]").click(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).attr("checked")){


        });
```

How can I combine both script in one.

Comment: Are the parameters always fixed or do they vary with the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having your:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chooseLocationType(location, title, demand){
        alert(demand);
        }
</script>
```

I would, as you don't specify where the values 'a', 'b', and 'c' come, add them as data attributes to your input

```
<input 
    name="tempstaff_location" 
    class="ques_radio" 
    id='tempstaff_location'
    value='location_' 
    data-location="a"
    data-title="b"
    data-demand="c"
    type="radio"/>
```

And finally access them in the event callback

```
$("input[name=tempstaff_location]").click(function(){
     if(jQuery(this).attr("checked")){
         chooseLocationType($(this).data('location'), $(this).data('title'), $(this).data('demand') );
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters vary with each element store them in a `data` tag within the element.  Then extract them in the click handler.  That way you can apply a single handler and do both.  It will be easier if you change chooseLocationType to accept an array of location types.

```
<input 
    name="tempstaff_location" 
    class="ques_radio" 
    id='tempstaff_location'
    value='location_' 
    type="radio"
    data-location="a,b,c" />

$('input[name=tempstaff_location]").click(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).attr("checked")){
           chooseLocationType( $(this).data('location').split(/,/) );
      }
});
```

If the values are fixed then it's much easier, you just move the call into your handler.

```
<input 
    name="tempstaff_location" 
    class="ques_radio" 
    id='tempstaff_location'
    value='location_' 
    type="radio"/>

$('input[name=tempstaff_location]").click(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).attr("checked")){
           chooseLocationType( 'a','b','c' );
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an inline `onclick` attribute, it is just a function, *basically* equivalent to this code:

```
element.onclick = function () {
    chooseLocationType( 'a','b','c' );
};
```

In your JavaScript file, you can just write

```
document.getElementById("tempstaff_location").onclick = function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        chooseLocationType( 'a','b','c' );
    }
}
```

Getting an element by its `id` is generally better than selecting it by a tagname and attriute.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call click event on page load instead of calling in radio button html. If following is the html:

```
<input 
    name="tempstaff_location" 
    class="ques_radio" 
    id='tempstaff_location'
    value='location_' 
    data-location="a"
    data-title="b"
    data-demand="c"
    type="radio"/>
```

Then you can call following script :

```
jQuery('input[name=tempstaff_location]').click(function(){
         if(jQuery(this).attr('checked')) {
           chooseLocationType(jQuery(this).attr('data-location'),jQuery(this).attr('data-title'),jQuery(this).attr('data-demand'));
         }
     });
```